# who is heading the development of ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to contact the person in charge for the development of ROS at Willow Garage.
I **don't** mean the CEO of the entire company, just the project leader that is coordinating the development of ROS.
Do you know who he/she is and how to contact him/her?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10027/who-is-heading-the-development-of-ros?/) by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2011-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Brian Gerkey is the Director of Open Source Development at Willow Garage, and coordinates the in-house ROS development there.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-24**:
Brian oversees *all* the open-source libraries we maintain, which includes ROS, OpenCV, PCL, and Gazebo.   I am the platform manager for ROS, and more specifically coordinate development of ROS itself.  Per Tully's answer below, though, we view ROS as a community effort, with many coordinators

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is made up of many, many different stacks and packages, each with its own maintainer. The maintainer for a given stack should be listed on it's wiki page or somewhere else in the repository. If their email is not also listed, an email to the ros-users mailing list is a good way to get in contact with a stack or package maintainer.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) on 2011-05-23**:
I know that there are many packages and many maintainer. What I mean was: "who is the leader at Willow Garage of the Robotic Operative System?". According to this page http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/about-us/leadership-team , I assume is BRIAN GERKEY...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS development is a community driven effort.  Please use the mailing list ros-developers@code.ros.org to contact the developers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3